# Fully Convolutional Network: How To

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I have studied the paper *[Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.06211)* (Shelhamer, Long and Darrell) and understand the process. They provide [extensive code in Caffe](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org). I have been analyzing the code for some time, but I however don't understand how to use this code for my own data. I have everything installed correctly (Caffe, Python, etc). I would, for example, like to:

1. Test the code on an arbitrary image and obtain a segmented image as an output.
2. Train the network on own image pairs {image, segmented image}.

Is there a tutorial I could follow on how to use this code. Or could someone give me a some guidelines. I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: I hope the links I added are the correct ones. This is recent work, so you'd be lucky to find organised tutorials. As you have studied the paper and code, your question would be improved (and more likely to get a useful answer) if it explained *specifically* what prevents you achieving your goals. The paper and code are both published in order to explain to readers how to replicate the work - so there's a *lot* to explain, too much for an answer on this site. Narrowing down your issue to the specific thing that blocks you will help. So what part of the paper/code do you not understand?

Comment: I tried out the python script `infer.py` included in the repository, which I understand would answer my first question (testing the code on an arbitrary image and obtaining a segmented image as output). I downloaded the required `.caffemodel` file and the code runs correctly (I see all the convolution, pooling etc. layers being displayed in the terminal). I however don't see/understand how I could obtain the segmented image from running this code.

Comment: In that script, the prediction is in the Python variable `out` - you will need to add your own code to visualise it (maybe just save as an image).

Comment: Thanks! I saved the numpy array as an image and it indeed gives a segmentation image of two classes. I guess I would have to change the code to see all 20 segmentation classes. So my 1st question is answered.

Comment: My 2nd question was how to train the network on my own images. I have a set of images that are labeled with colored blobs according to the Pascal VOC challenge Matlab script `VOClabelcolormap.m`. I want to reuse the VGG16 weights to initialize learning and then train the network on my own {image, labelled image} datasets. Is there a specific script that does this within the provided code? I understand that I would need to download the VGG16 `.caffemodel`, are there any other files that I need to download?